# Problema para guardatos en procedimiento almacenado usando c# y SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure

Edité la ultima parte de mi pregunta en base a las respuestas que me han dado, y puse la consulta que se envía desde mi aplicación a la base de datos.

El día de ayer me ayudaron con un procedimiento almacenado que tengo, lo ordené bien y comparé que los nombres de los campos estuviesen bien escritos, pero el día de hoy me encuentro con otro problema, esta es la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La linea 489 a la que hace referencia el mensaje en mi código es:

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Probé con:

```
comando.ExecuteScalar();
```

Pero no.

Busqué en otros foros e incluso en stackoverflow en ingles y todos dicen: "cuenta cuantos datos le tienes que pasar al procedimiento", son 23 y me sigue saltando el error a pesar de que previamente revisé que estuviera bien escrito, dejo el código del procedimiento y de mi función:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zf_Boleta_Crear]
    @Idboleta       int output,
    @IdCliente  int,
    @IdMonedaCIF    int,
    @IdMonedaVenta  int,
    @IdTipoDoc int,
    @TipoIngreso    char(1),
    @Archivo    varchar(60),
    @sTipoDocumento char(2),
    @sNroBoleta int,
    @sLineas    char(3),
    @sFecha datetime,
    @sNroContrato   char(4),
    @sTipoMovimiento    char(2),
    @sAñoZ  char(4),
    @sNumeroZ   char(6),
    @sItemZ char(4),
    @sMoneda    char(4),
    @sValorCIF  decimal(18,2),
    @sMonedaVenta   char(4),
    @sValorVenta    decimal(18,2),
    @Cadena varchar(150),
    @Estado char(1),
    @CreadoPor  varchar(25)/*,  
    @Local      int*/



AS

SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @IdMes_AñoTrabajo int

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Traer ID Mes_Año de Trabajo
select @IdMes_AñoTrabajo=IdMes_AñoTrabajado from zf_BloqueosMes_Año where Mes=month(@sFecha) and Año=year(@sFecha) and Bloqueado=0 
if @IdMes_AñoTrabajo is null select @IdMes_AñoTrabajo=min(IdMes_AñoTrabajado) from zf_BloqueosMes_Año where Bloqueado=0
---if @dv is null set @dv=0

    INSERT
        dbo.zf_Boleta
        (
        IdCliente,
        IdMonedaCIF,
        IdMonedaVenta,
        IdTipoDoc,
        TipoIngreso,
        Archivo,
        sTipoDocumento,
        sNroBoleta,
        sLineas,
        sFecha,
        sNroContrato,
        sTipoMovimiento,
        sAñoZ,
        sNumeroZ,
        sItemZ,
        sMoneda,
        sValorCIF,
        sMonedaVenta,
        sValorVenta,
        Cadena,
        Estado,
        CreadoPor,
        IdMes_AñoTrabajado
        )
    VALUES
        (
        @IdCliente,
        @IdMonedaCIF,
        @IdMonedaVenta,
        @IdTipoDoc,
        @TipoIngreso,
        @Archivo,
        @sTipoDocumento,
        @sNroBoleta,
        @sLineas,
        @sFecha,
        @sNroContrato,
        @sTipoMovimiento,
        @sAñoZ,
        @sNumeroZ,
        @sItemZ,
        @sMoneda,
        @sValorCIF,
        @sMonedaVenta,
        @sValorVenta,
        @Cadena,
        @Estado,
        @CreadoPor,
        @IdMes_AñoTrabajo
    )

    IF @@ERROR != 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('R -2; Se a generado un error cuando se ejecutaba una transacción en la Base de Datos: ZonaFranca. El procedimiento que genero el error se llama : dbo.zf_Boleta_Crear; Registro ID : %s',10, 2, @IdCliente  ) WITH LOG
        RETURN -2
    END

    SET @Idboleta = @@IDENTITY

COMMIT TRANSACTION
RETURN 0
```

La primera parte del while es para ir a buscar unos id a otras tablas y darle formato a una fecha, pero no creo que eso afecte.

```
if (mostrarDatos != 0 && HayErrores == 0)
{
int IdMoneda = 0;
int IdMonedaVenta = 0;
int IdTipoDoc = 0;
string Fecha = "";
string cadenaconexion = @"Data Source=IP.ip.ip.ip\rentas;Initial Catalog=ZonaFranca;Integrated Security=False; user id=**;password=********";
SqlConnection LaConexion = null;
SqlTransaction LaTransaccion = null;
comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

try
{
    LaConexion = new SqlConnection();
    LaConexion.ConnectionString = cadenaconexion;
    LaConexion.Open();
    LaTransaccion = LaConexion.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("zf_Boleta_Crear", LaConexion, LaTransaccion);
    comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


    int i = 0;
    while (i <= ContArchivo - 1)
    {
        IdMoneda = Datos.ObtenerIdMonedaCIF(mCIF[i]);
        IdMonedaVenta = Datos.ObtenerIdMonedaCIF(mVenta[i]);
        IdTipoDoc = Datos.ObtenerIdTipoDoc(salida[i]);
        Fecha = Datos.ObtenerFecha(fDocumento[i].ToString());

        comando.Parameters.Add("@Idboleta", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
        comando.Parameters["@Idboleta"].Value = 0;

        comando.Parameters.Add("@IdCliente", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
        comando.Parameters["@IdCliente"].Value = IDCliente;

        comando.Parameters.Add("@IdMonedaCIF", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
        comando.Parameters["@IdMonedaCIF"].Value = IdMoneda; //zf_Moneda hay que sacar el valor de acá

        comando.Parameters.Add("@IdMonedaVenta", SqlDbType.Int,10);
        comando.Parameters["@IdMonedaVenta"].Value = IdMonedaVenta; //zf_Moneda

        comando.Parameters.Add("@IdTipoDoc", SqlDbType.Int, 10);
        comando.Parameters["@IdTipoDoc"].Value = IdTipoDoc; //zf_TipoDoc hay que sacar el valor de acá

        comando.Parameters.Add("@TipoIngreso", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
        comando.Parameters["@TipoIngreso"].Value = "M";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@Archivo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 60);
        comando.Parameters["@Archivo"].Value = "";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sTipoDocumento", SqlDbType.Char, 2);
        comando.Parameters["@sTipoDocumento"].Value = tDocEntrada[i];

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sNroBoleta", SqlDbType.Int, 20);
        comando.Parameters["@sNroBoleta"].Value = nDocumento[i];

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sLineas", SqlDbType.Char, 3);
        comando.Parameters["@sLineas"].Value = "";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sFecha", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        comando.Parameters["@sFecha"].Value = Fecha;

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sNroContrato", SqlDbType.Char, 4);
        comando.Parameters["@sNroContrato"].Value = "";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sTipoMovimiento", SqlDbType.Char, 2);
        comando.Parameters["@sTipoMovimiento"].Value = "";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sAñoZ", SqlDbType.Char, 4);
        comando.Parameters["@sAñoZ"].Value = "";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sNumeroZ", SqlDbType.Char, 6);
        comando.Parameters["@sNumeroZ"].Value = "";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sItemZ", SqlDbType.Char, 4);
        comando.Parameters["@sItemZ"].Value = "";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sMoneda", SqlDbType.Char, 4);
        comando.Parameters["@sMoneda"].Value = mCIF[i];

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sValorCIF", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        comando.Parameters["@sValorCIF"].Value = vCIF[i];

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sMonedaVenta", SqlDbType.Char, 4);
        comando.Parameters["@sMonedaVenta"].Value = mVenta[i];

        comando.Parameters.Add("@sValorVenta", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        comando.Parameters["@sValorVenta"].Value = vVenta[i];

        comando.Parameters.Add("@Cadena", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150);
        comando.Parameters["@Cadena"].Value = "";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@Estado", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
        comando.Parameters["@Estado"].Value = "P";

        comando.Parameters.Add("@CreadoPor", SqlDbType.Char, 30);
        comando.Parameters["@CreadoPor"].Value = NombreCliente;

        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        i++;
    }
    LaConexion.Close();
}
```

No sé qué se me puede estar escapando.

Lo otro: existe algún tipo de visualizador en donde yo pueda ver como se está enviando esta consulta? (se que es otra pregunta pero tiene relación directa con mi problema)

======

Acorde a las respuestas que me han dado, pude ver la consulta que se envía desde mi aplicación a la base de datos, es la siguiente:
Lo que encuentro raro son las **N** que aparecen.

```
exec zf_Boleta_Crear @Idboleta=N'',@IdCliente=N'4',@IdMonedaCIF=5,@IdMonedaVenta=4,@IdTipoDoc=7,@TipoIngreso=N'M',@Archivo=N'',@sTipoDocumento=N'Z ',@sNroBoleta=N'0260015234',@sLineas=N'05',@sFecha=N'2019-04-30',@sNroContrato=N'',@sTipoMovimiento=N'',@sAñoZ=N'',@sNumeroZ=N'',@sItemZ=N'',@sMoneda=N'USDL',@sValorCIF=N'000000000.79',@sMonedaVenta=N'PECH',@sValorVenta=N'000000490.00',@Cadena=N'',@Estado=N'P',@CreadoPor=N'patio'
```

Comment: Eso pasa sólo cuando hay más de una línea? Creo que estás duplicando la cantidad de los parámetros enviados al procedimiento en la segunda iteración del bucle. Trata sacar los `comando.Parameters.Add` del while y deja sólo la asignación.

Comment: no es duplicado, por lo que entiendo primero le asigno el tipo de dato que envío y después le mando el dato con .Value

Comment: Eso es claro, pero en la primer iteración estás enviando 23 parámetros, en la segunda estás mandando 46, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: de verdad? según yo, enviaba 23, después 23 de nuevo con otros datos y así

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imagenes de los errores, publica directamente el texto del mensaje de error (copiar y pegar). Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate si sé eso, lo he visto en otras publicaciones y en mías pero para este caso no me dejaba copiar todo ese texto. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Te esta pasando esto porque estas agregando los parámetros al comando dentro del while

```
comando = crearComando();
While (....) {
comando.Parameters.Add("@Idboleta", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
comando.Parameters["@Idboleta"].Value = 0;
// .... 
i++;
}
```

Tienes que poner el `Parameters.Add()` antes del bucle sino en cada pasada estas indicando al comando otro nuevo grupo de parámetros y estas duplicando la cantidad de parámetros de acuerdo a la cantidad de pasadas del bucle.

Comment: lo voy a hacer y comento, gracias

Comment: lo ordené como dices pero salta el mismo error. En otra respuesta me recomiendan poner un punto de interrupción en *comando.ExecuteNonQuery()* y lo que veo que sale marcado con X es: *EventSink* y *InternalSmiConnection*

Comment: o comando.Parameters.Clear();

Comment: Fijate con el SQL Profiler a ver que esta recibiendo el SQL y de esta manera vas a ver que parametro es el extra y ayudarnos a darte una ayuda mejor.

Comment: Por otro lado, nunca utilices la ñ como nombre de parámetro o variable en los SP o c#.... mañana agarras una pc que este todo en ingles y te va a fallar todo, ni hablar si el desarrollo lo llegar a continuar un equipo tercerizado de la India. Por convenición siempre es en ingles o al menos sin caracteres especiales de un idioma.

Comment: @AndresLozadaMosto gracias, lo voy a plantear para próximos casos, este es un procedimiento que ya tiene sus años y que ahora se está reutilizando

Comment: @AndresLozadaMosto esto me muestra el SQL Profiler: **exec zf_Boleta_Crear @Idboleta=N'',@IdCliente=N'4',@IdMonedaCIF=5,@IdMonedaVenta=4,@IdTipoDoc=6,@TipoIngreso=N'M',@Archivo=N'',@sTipoDocumento=N'Z ',@sNroBoleta=N'0130125568',@sLineas=N'',@sFecha=N'2019-04-01',@sNroContrato=N'',@sTipoMovimiento=N'',@sAñoZ=N'',@sNumeroZ=N'',@sItemZ=N'',@sMoneda=N'USDL',@sValorCIF=N'000000001.42',@sMonedaVenta=N'PECH',@sValorVenta=N'000001922.00',@Cadena=N'',@Estado=N'P',@CreadoPor=N'patio'**

Comment: Excelnte, lo ejecutaste desde el SQL Manager Studio a ver si te funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Si pones un punto de interrupción en momento.ExecuteNonQuery(); podrás llegar a ver el comando SQL que vas a ejecutar.

Dado que tú primer parámetro esta definido como output no es un parámetro a pasar sino a leer, prueba a modificar tú codigo con lo siguiente:

```
while (i <= ContArchivo -1)
{
    ...


    SqlParameter idboleta = new SqlParameter("@Idboleta", SqlDbType.Int);
    idboleta.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(idboleta);

    ...

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Recuperas el valor devuelto por el procedimiento almacenado, por ejemplo<.
    MessageBox.Show(idboleta.Value.ToString());
    i++;
    comando.Parameters.Clear();  //como comenta @gbianchi
}
```

Comment: voy probar poniendo el punto de interrupción, y si no es ExecuteNonQuery, cual uso, ExecuteScalar?

Comment: Sí debería ser ExecuteNonQuery porque no estás regresando ningún conjunto de datos. Lo único útil de esta respuesta es la sugerencia del punto de interrupción.

Comment: @Luis Si regresa un dato. Al definir el primer parametro (IDBoleta) del procedimiento almacenado como de tipo output y entonces debe ejecutar la llamada con ExecuteScalar()

Comment: ese Idboleta es auto incremental, sacando el campo de mi función me sigue saltando el mismo error lo ejecute como **ExecuteScalar** o **ExecuteNonQuery**

Answer (score -2):

asi de primera vista el error que te muestra es de la linea que manda llamar el SP sin mostrarte el error en concreto, intenta probar tu SP desde MySQL antes de de hacerlo con VS asi descartas un posible error en el llamado o en la conexión, asegurate de que los tipos de datos que estas poniendo en las variables sean iguales al origen de datos, ya sabes, Int en Int, tambien longitudes.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]. Tene en cuenta que AP esta usando sql server, no mysql.